# Throttle Akka Ask

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to throttle my `ask` requests to a consumerActor.

```
val throttler: ActorRef =
Source.actorRef(bufferSize = 1000, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
  .throttle(10, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
  .to(Sink.foreach[Any](msg => consumerActor ! msg))
  .run()
```

with

```
aLotOfItems.map(items =>
  val itemsFuture = (throttler ? consumeItems(items)).mapTo[Future[String]]
  itemsFuture flatMap {x => x}
}).toVector
```

This does send msgs to the consumerActor but I seem to lose the response as I tried with 2 items but the request just hangs.

I think I need to change the `tell` in the `Sink.foreach` to an ask or something that can handle a response

Solution: Got it to work using the selected answer below. I had to add

```
val answer = Source(...) (from the selected answer below)
sender ! answer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're expecting responses from `throttler`, but `throttler` is not sending replies and is unable to do so because it doesn't have a reference to the original sender.

If `consumerActor` replies to the sender of each `consumeItems(i)` message with a `Future[String]`, then one way to achieve what you're trying to do is to create a `Source` from `aLotOfItems` and use a combination of `mapAsync` and `ask` to throttle messages to the actor. The replies from the actor can be accumulated in a `Sink`. Something like:

```
val sink = Sink.seq[String]

val result =
  Source(aLotOfItems)
    .map(consumeItems(_))
    .mapAsync(parallelism = 5)(item => (consumerActor ? item).mapTo[Future[String]])
    .mapAsync(parallelism = 5)(identity)
    .runWith(sink)

// Future[Seq[String]]
```

Comment: where would you declare the `Source`?

Comment: Also I tried `Source(aLotOfItems)` but I got a type mismatch of `Expected: Iterable[NotInferedT] Actual: Vector[Item]`.

Comment: What is the type of `aLotOfItems`?

Comment: yup it is a `Vector[Item]`. However now the `Source` is `Future[Done]`. I used to have that line set to a variable that resulted in `Future[String]`

Comment: basically I had a `Vector` of `ItemResults` that I could use, but now I have a `Done` instead

Comment: I updated the example to show how you can define a sink and get its materialized value. In this case, a `Future[Seq[String]]` of the replies from `consumerActor`. Does this help?

Comment: It does, now I try to `Await.result(resultFuture.flatMap(identity), Duration.apply(100, "seconds"))` and the request just hangs, it seems like it goes through but the response is just not coming back from the `result`

Comment: Does `consumerActor` reply to the sender?

Comment: It does with `sender ! itemFuture` where `itemFuture=ws.url(...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153286/discussion-between-chunjef-and-jeff).